# Object reference required for non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#

I want to use the Caching.Cache(...) method, like so:

```
Cache.Insert("Interview Questions", datatable, sqlcachedep)
```

or

```
System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert("Reading List", datatable, sqlcachedep);
```

There is no problem with the variables, but I get this error message in either case:

> Error 1 - An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.Caching.Cache.Insert(string, object, System.Web.Caching.CacheDependency)'

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Umm, besides not calling it as if it were a static method?

Comment: Actually the two parameter objects were private. Making them public has got rid of the error msg.

Answer (score 17):

It's saying the correct thing. You should try something like:

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(...);
```

[`Cache.Insert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.insert.aspx) is a not a static method (static methods are indicated by an "S" near the method icon in the documentation.) You need an instance to call the `Insert` method on. `HttpContext.Current.Cache` returns the `Cache` object associated with the current application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
Page.Cache.Insert()
```

(I'm assuming you're talking ASP.Net).  You're calling on Cache as the class, not as the instance of it.

Comment: Actually the two parameter objects were private. Making them public has got rid of the error msg.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (from memory):

```
HttpApplication.Context.Cache.Insert("Reading List", datatable, sqlcachedep);
```