# Post parameter is always null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

Since upgrading to RC for WebAPI I'm having some real odd issue when calling POST on my WebAPI.
I've even gone back to the basic version generated on new project. So:

```
public void Post(string value)
{
}
```

and calling from Fiddler:

```
Header:
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:60725
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 29

Body:
{
    "value": "test"
}
```

When I debug, the string "value" is never being assigned to. It's just always NULL.
Anyone having this issue?

(I first saw the issue with a more complex type)

The problem is not only bound to ASP.NET MVC 4, the same problem occurs for a fresh ASP.NET MVC 3 project after RC installation

Comment: Just to add to the problem - it's not exclusive to JSON, it happens with XML too.

Comment: I have been batling with this for two days and after reading every article I could find about it, it turned out to be as simple as formatting the JSON string correctly in the WebRequest: The data must start and end with double quotes and if you then use single quotes throughout your json data it all plays nice.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Since you have only one parameter, you could try decorating it with the `[FromBody]` attribute, or change the method to accept a DTO with value as a property, as I suggested here: [MVC4 RC WebApi parameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10955629/mvc4-rc-webapi-parameter-binding/10956025)

UPDATE: The official ASP.NET site was updated today with an excellent explanation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

In a nutshell, when sending a single simple type in the body, send just the value prefixed with an equal sign (=), e.g. body:

`=test`

Comment: I did give the [FromBody] a whirl but it had no change

Comment: Pass just the value (i.e. not as a JSON object) and it should work, according to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx

Comment: `[FromBody]` works for us, but in our view this is a step backwards. With the beta we could have multiple simple type arguments and they were bound just fine to methods in our `ApiController`s. So while the explanation you reference does explain, I strongly disagree :-)

Comment: The append `=` in front never ever worked for me, until I followed Jim's advice in his comment (not as a JSON object) and it worked. This is key! I really don't like how picky WebAPI is.

Comment: This is so stupid and annoying that I don't know if to upvote or downvote the answer that helped me solve my problem... Why on earth does it have to be in this format? (Sorry for the attitude, just wasted too much time on this, and it doesn't make any sense... `:(` ). You should really add support for the format people expect it to accept.

Comment: Thanks! How on Earth should we know that we have to remove the parameter name when sending only one parameter? Which birdbrain came up with this idea?

Comment: Prepending the "=" to value and `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` worked for me.

Comment: @ianrathbone you can define to get a jObject at the method declension to receive any json object

Comment: This is so stupid. I want to punch the developer in the face that decided to switch from the old json or object way to using an = sign. now i have to append = to the variable. Who ever said yes lets do this, should be fired at microsoft.

Comment: @Leon your answer is on page 2, it should be on the first page and top. That is the correct way to do it!

Comment: For **Swagger** or **postman**, refer dvc.junior's answer below. Send body as **"value"**, including quotes.

Comment: A model binding failure can cause the entire object to be passed in as null.  For instance if you have an `int` property in your view model and the client is passing a `null` it will fail to bind. e.g. expecting `class Model { public int value {get; set;} }` and POSTing `{"value": null}`

Answer (score 124):

I have been scratching my head over this today.

My solution is to change the `[FromBody]` to a `HttpRequestMessage`, essentially moving up the HTTP stack.

In my case I am sending data across the wire which is zipped json which is then base64'd.  All this from an android app.

The original signature of my web endpoint looked like this (using `[FromBody]`) :

[image: My original endpoint]

My fix for this issue was to revert to using a `HttpRequestMessage` for the signature of my endpoint.

[image]

You can then get access to the post data using this line of code:

[image]

This works and allows you access to the raw untouched post data.  You don't have to mess around with fiddler putting an = sign at the beginning of your string or changing the content-type.

As an aside, I first tried to following one of the answers above which was to change the content type to: "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  For raw data this is bad advice because it strips out + characters.

So a base64 string that starts like this: "MQ0AAB+LCAAAAAA" ends up like this "MQ0AAB LCAAAAAA"! Not what you want.

Another benefit of using `HttpRequestMessage` is that you get access to all the http headers from within your endpoint.

Comment: Excellent solution... took me 9 hours to find this, sorted my issue out after I removed [FromBody] string value and substituted it with HttpRequestMessage

Comment: Works like a charm! but isn't there a way to use an actual parameter type of a certain object? e.g, parameter of type Order for a web api method?

Comment: Just a side note, you don't NEED the `HttpRequestMessage request` in the method signature, as you always have this already. In the method body it can be accessed on the `Request` object. eg `Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

Comment: Usually this problem is because your JSON object is incorrect. I have found this is always because in the constructor has an invalid type and Json doesn't know how to convert it' Like a Guid to a string. So either add the converter via settings or add a blank constructor and you don't need to back to old code like this.

Comment: The easiest way is to switch the object to a string and then try and convert it and you'll see the JSON error. Check you're headers also.

Answer (score 75):

I've just had this occur using Fiddler. The problem was that I hadn't specified `Content-Type`.

Try including a header for `Content-Type` in your POST request.

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

---

Alternatively, as per comments below, you may need to include a JSON header

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, except that I needed to set the Content-Type: application/json

Comment: As specified in the post - I had already added Content-Type: application/json

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlencoded did not work for me, Content-Type: application/json did.

Comment: Regardless of the content-type, if you only have one parameter you must send only the value without the parameter name in the body of the request. So id=13 won't work. You need to send 13 alone. See Jim's answer.

Comment: I had to use `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` , for a complete example see [Complete Cient and Server](http://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/)

Answer (score 62):

I've ran into this problem as well, and this is how I solved my problem

webapi code:

```
public void Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    string value = data.value;
    /* do stuff */
}
```

client code:

```
$.post( "webapi/address", { value: "some value" } );
```

Comment: This works if the client is sending JSON.  If I am sending a simple value such as the string `some value`, then `data` is null.

Comment: easy, change your client code to send back a js object.

Comment: Great and clean way to get data from JSON

Comment: If you are sending json, then    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

Comment: Great way. Even you can get incoming data with like this.
```var _data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data.ToString());
string value = _data.value;
```

Answer (score 47):

I was using `Postman` and I was doing the same mistake.. passing the `value` as json object instead of string

```
{
    "value": "test"
}
```

Clearly the above one is ***wrong*** when the api parameter is of type string.

So, just pass the string in double quotes in the api body:

```
"test"
```

Comment: This was my issue, and likely the real solution to the question.  A JSON-encoded string has quotes

Comment: I also encountered this issue on Postman. It turns out that I wrongly chose "form-data" instead of "raw" for Body when the Content-Type is set to be application/json.

You can refer to zzyykk123456's screenshots at the Issues of aspnet Github: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/2202

Comment: This worked for me.  Using Swagger (swashbuckle) I have to set Content Type: application/json and use double quotes.

Comment: Exactly my Issue But I have to note that in Ajax requests you should do 'data: JSON.stringify("YourString")'

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi I have just encountered this on ajax and saw that actually using `JSON.stringify` was causing my `[frombody]` to be `null`. After setting the data field to a string value (that is a json string) it worked.

Answer (score 19):

Try creating a class to serve as the data model, then send a JSON object with properties matching the properties of your data model class. (Note: I have tested this and it works with the newest MVC 4 RC 2012 that I just downloaded today).

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(ValueModel model)
{
    return Request.CreateResponse<string>(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Value Recieved: " + model.Value);
}

public class ValueModel
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The below JSON object is sent in HTTP-POST body, content-type is application/json

```
{ "value": "In MVC4 Beta you could map to simple types like string, but testing with RC 2012 I have only been able to map to DataModels and only JSON (application/json) and url-encoded (application/x-www-form-urlencoded body formats have worked. XML is not working for some reason" }
```

I believe the reason why you have to create a data model class is because simple values are assumed to be from the url parameters, and a single complex value is assumed to be from the body. They do have the `[FromBody]` and `[FromUrl]` attributes, but using `[FromBody] string value` still did not work for me. Seems like they are still working out a lot of bugs so I'm sure this will change in the future.

**Edit:**
Got XML to work in the body. The default XML serializer was changed to DataContractSerializer instead of XmlSerializer. Putting the following line in my Global.asax file fixed this issue ([reference](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization))

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
```

Comment: this worked for me with 
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";

Answer (score 17):

After some tries, I think the default behavior is correct and there is nothing to hack.

The only trick is: if your post method argument is `string` like below, you should send **a plain string with double quotes** in the body (when using ajax or postman), e.g.,

```
//send "{\"a\":1}" in body to me, note the outer double quotes
[HttpPost("api1")]
public String PostMethod1([FromBody]string value)
{
    return "received " + value; //  "received {\"a\":1}"
}
```

Otherwise if you send a json string in the post body **without outer double quotes** and escaped inner quotes, then it should be able to be parsed to the model class (the argument type), e.g., `{"a":1, "b":2}`

```
public class MyPoco{
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

//send {"a":1, "b":2} in body to me
[HttpPost("api2")]
public String PostMethod2([FromBody]MyPoco value)
{
    return "received " + value.ToString();  //"received your_namespace+MyPoco"
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I was looking for a solution to this problem for some minutes now, so I'll share my solution.

If you post a model your model needs to have an empty/default constructor, otherwise the model can't be created, obviously.
Be careful while refactoring. ;)

Comment: Refactoring is exactly what bit me here, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 12):

For those who are having the same issue with **Swagger** or **Postman** like I did, if you are passing a simple attribute as string in a post, even with the "ContentType" specified, you still going to get a null value.

Passing just:

MyValue

Will get in the controller as null.

But if you pass:

**"MyValue"**

The value will get right.

The quotes made the difference here. Of course, this is only for Swagger and Postman. For instance, in a Frontend app using Angular this should be resolved by the framework automaticly.

Comment: Also if you happen to be passing json with quotation marks in it you can surround the whole thing in single apostrophe marks.

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me:

1. Create a C# DTO class, with a property for every attribute you want to pass from jQuery/Ajax

   ```
   public class EntityData
   {
       public string Attr1 { get; set; }
       public string Attr2 { get; set; }
   }
   ```
2. Define the web api method:

   ```
   [HttpPost()]
   public JObject AddNewEntity([FromBody] EntityData entityData)
   {
   ```
3. Call the web api as such:

   ```
   var entityData = {
       "attr1": "value1",
       "attr2": "value2"
   };

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "/api/YOURCONTROLLER/addnewentity",
       async: true,
       cache: false,
       data: JSON.stringify(entityData),
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
           ...
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks for posting this, i tried numerous samples but this worked for me !

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issue and found that when changing the Content Type to "application/json" did not fix the problem. However "application/json; charset=utf-8" worked.

Comment: Yup, Web API won't deserialize without the charset=utf-8. https://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue where the request object for my Web API method was always null. I noticed that since the controller action name was prefixed with "Get", Web API treated this as a HTTP GET rather than a POST. After renaming the controller action, it now works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

Double check your data types. The dotnet model binder will not convert a float to an integer (and I'm assuming other related concepts). This will cause the entire model to be rejected.

If you have json like this:

```
{
    "shoeSize": 10.5
}
```

but your c# model looks like this:

```
class Shoe{
    public int shoeSize;
}
```

the model binder will reject the model and you will get null.

Answer (score 4):

Met with a similar problem in ASP.NET Core and another possible cause is ASP.NET binding (silent) failure due to various reasons such as **sending null to be bound to a not null property**:

```
{
    "prop1":1139357,
    "prop2":1139356,

    "items":[
        {"key":"15","someprop":34,"notnullprop":null},
        {"key":"16","someprop":34,"notnullprop":null},
        {"key":"22","someprop":34,"notnullprop":null}]
}
```

On such case there is **no exception being thrown and the whole model will be null**, even if this happens deep inside the object hierarchy.

Answer (score 3):

With Angular, I was able to pass data in this format:

```
 data: '=' + JSON.stringify({ u: $scope.usrname1, p: $scope.pwd1 }),
 headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8' }
```

And in Web API Controler:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public Hashtable Post([FromBody]string jsonString)
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, string>>(jsonString);
        string username = data["u"];
        string pwd = data["p"];
   ......
```

Alternatively, I could also post JSON data like this:

```
    data: { PaintingId: 1, Title: "Animal show", Price: 10.50 }
```

And, in the controller, accept a class type like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string POST(Models.PostModel pm)
    {

     ....
    }
```

Either way works, if you have an established public class in the API then post JSON, otherwise post '=' + JSON.stringify({..: ..., .. : ... })

Answer (score 3):

In my case the problem was that the parameter was a string and not an object, i changed the parameter to be JObject of Newsoft.Json and it works.

Answer (score 3):

If you are sure about your sent JSON then you must trace your API carefully:

1. Install `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing` package
2. Add `config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();` in the `WebApiConfig` class inside `Register` method.

Now look at the Debug output and you will probably find an invalid `ModelState` log entry.

If `ModelState` is invalid you may find the real cause in its `Errors`:

No one can even guess such an exception:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

Comment: you saved my life. Getting null as the model and after installing the package, found that my JSON isn't in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

Adding line

```
        ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

to the end of function `protected void Application_Start()` in Global.asax.cs fixed similar problem for me in ASP.NET MVC3.

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately it didn't help. I'll keep the line in for the time being as it may help out anyway!

Comment: Just to add the same problems occur when I post XML

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a **DataContractSerializer** for your Xml Formatter or JSON Formatter, you need to get rid of it.
I had this in my WebApiConfig file:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
     config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
     );    

     var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
     jsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;
}
```

Simply I comment out `jsonFormatter.UseDataContractJsonSerializer = true;`and my input parameter isn't null anymore. Thanks to 'Despertar' for giving me a clue.

Answer (score 2):

For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message body, using a media-type formatter.

Please check if you got any `[Serializable]` attribute decorating your model class.

Remove the attribute to see if it works. This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you put [FromBody] annotation and you have a Dto object as a parameter to your method and still not able to get the data through, start looking into the properties and fields of your DTO.

I had this same problem, where my DTO was coming null. I found the reason was that one of the properties was pointing into an ***object that cannot be serialised*** :( which causes the media-formatter to fail to parse the data. Thus the object was always null. 
Hope it helps others too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue of getting null as parameter, but it was related to large objects. It turned out the problem was related to IIS max length. It can be configured in web.config.

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7" maxRequestLength="1073741824" />
  </system.web>
```

I wonder why Web API suppressed the error and sends null objects to my APIs. I found the error using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Tracing.

Answer (score 2):

JSON.stringify(...) solved my issues

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not an answer to this question, but I came across it when searching for a solution to my problem.

In my case, the complex type was not being bound but I was not doing a POST, I was doing a GET with querystring parameters. The solution was to add [FromUri] to the arg:

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<MyModel> Get([FromUri] MyComplexType input)
    {
        // input is not null as long as [FromUri] is present in the method arg
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because the body of the request is *ignored* (and sometimes causes an error) when using GET.  The reason it works now is b/c you are now passing params on query string, and your body is empty **as should be on a GET**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in Fiddler. I already had `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8` or `Content-Type: application/json` in the request header.

My request body was also a plain string, and in Fiddler I had written: `{'controller':'ctrl'}`. This made the string parameter in my POST method be `null`.

**Fix**: remember to use quotation marks, thereby indicating a string. That is, I fixed it by writing `"{'controller':'ctrl'}"`. (Note: when writing JSON, either be sure to use apostrophes or escape the quotation marks like this: `"{\"controller\":\"ctrl\"}"`).

Comment: I had to do the same thing in Postman.  But I don't need to do this when I call Spring services.  Seems like a problem on the .Net side.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way I found to deal with simple JSON object that I pass into MVC 6 is getting the the type of the post parameter like NewtonSoft jObject:

```
public ActionResult Test2([FromBody] jObject str)
{
        return Json(new { message = "Test1 Returned: "+ str }); ;
}
```

Comment: Test(`[FromBody] object body, [FromHeader(Name="Content-Type")] string bodyMediaType`) could work better as checking `bodyMediaType  == "application.json"` before casting body to JObject provides an opportunity for alterntives.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for me is going full HTTP as below:

```
[Route("api/open")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> open(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var json = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();            
    WS_OpenSession param = jss.Deserialize<WS_OpenSession>(json);
    return param.sessionid;
}
```

and then deserializing the string to the object you expect in the post body.
For me, WS_OpenSession is a class that contained sessionid, user and key.

You can from there use the param object and access its properties.

Very very effective.

I did say sourced from this url:

http://bizcoder.com/posting-raw-json-to-web-api

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but anyone who stumbles across a NULL value passed when using a controller simply add "=" to the front of your POST request.

The controller also passed a NULL value when I used the **application/json** Content-Type. Note the "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" Content-Type below. The return type from the API however is "application/json".

```
 public static string HttpPostRequest(string url, Dictionary<string, string> postParameters)
    {
        string postData = "=";

        foreach (string key in postParameters.Keys)
        {
            postData += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key) + "="
                  + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(postParameters[key]) + ",";
        }

        HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
        myHttpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        myHttpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

        Stream requestStream = myHttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream();
        requestStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        requestStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

        Stream responseStream = myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream, System.Text.Encoding.Default);

        string pageContent = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

        myStreamReader.Close();
        responseStream.Close();

        myHttpWebResponse.Close();

        return pageContent;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

it doesn't matter what type of value you wish to post, just enclose it within the quotation marks, to get it as string. Not for complex types.

javascript:

```
    var myData = null, url = 'api/' + 'Named/' + 'NamedMethod';

    myData = 7;

    $http.post(url, "'" + myData + "'")
         .then(function (response) { console.log(response.data); });

    myData = "some sentence";

    $http.post(url, "'" + myData + "'")
         .then(function (response) { console.log(response.data); });

    myData = { name: 'person name', age: 21 };

    $http.post(url, "'" + JSON.stringify(myData) + "'")
         .then(function (response) { console.log(response.data); });

    $http.post(url, "'" + angular.toJson(myData) + "'")
         .then(function (response) { console.log(response.data); });
```

c#:

```
    public class NamedController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public int NamedMethod([FromBody] string value)
        {
            return value == null ? 1 : 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty late to this but was having similar issues and after a day of going through a lot of the answers here and getting background I have found the easiest/lightweight solution to pass back one or more parameters to a Web API 2 Action is as follows:

This assumes that you know how to setup a Web API controller/action with correct routing, if not refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api.

First the Controller Action, this solution also requires the Newtonsoft.Json library.

```
[HttpPost]
public string PostProcessData([FromBody]string parameters) {
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parameters)) {
        JObject json = JObject.Parse(parameters);

        // Code logic below
        // Can access params via json["paramName"].ToString();
    }
    return "";
}
```

Client Side using jQuery

```
var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({ param1: "value1", param2: "value2"...});
$.post('/Web_API_URI', { '': dataToSend }).done(function (data) {
     console.debug(data); // returned data from Web API
 });
```

The key issue I found was making sure you only send a single overall parameter back to the Web API and make sure it has no name just the value `{ '': dataToSend }`otherwise your value will be null on the server side.

With this you can send one or many parameters to the Web API in a JSON structure and you don't need to declare any extra objects server side to handle complex data. The JObject also allows you to dynamically iterate over all parameters passed in allowing easier scalability should your parameters change over time. Hopefully that helps someone out that was struggling like me.

Answer (score 1):

Someday i just had the same problem as you, in my case the problem was that, the class that i was using as json container, didn't have the get and set definitions so, the API didn't know how to fill the JSON data into the instance.

My example json class would be .

```
public class Usuario
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see there you have get and set respectively, so it will fill.

If you remove them, your will get the post creating a null instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

I had also an issue with **[FromBody]** attribute not working when **POST** json with enum string value instead of int was sent.

The request object was silentely set to NULL
Note I was not using ApiController. When I tried the same with ApiController I got proper exception with information, that string cannot be parsed to appropriate enum

Adding

```
options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
```

Fixed the enum parameter and whole object

Answer (score 0):

Correct passing single parameter in body to WebAPI  works this code `$.post(url, { '': productId }`

And catching it in action `[HttpPost] public ShoppingCartAddRemoveViewModel Delete([FromBody]string value)`

Key is to use magic word 'value'. It may be also int, or some primitive type.
No matter content-type or header corrections
Mess is that this code doesn't work in mvc post action.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your action method is expecting a simple type i.e., a string parameter value. What you are providing is an object.

*There are 2 solutions to your problem.*

1. Create a simple class with "**value**" property and then use that class as parameter, in which case Web API model binding will read JSON object from request and bind it to your param object "values" property.
2. Just pass string value "**test**", and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

API:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool UpdateTicketStatus(Ticket t)
{    
    string Id=t.Id;
}
```

Model:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string History { get; set; }
}
```

Using Post man tool send the content as json with raw data as below. It works

{
    "Id":"169248",
    "AssignedTo":"xxxx",
    "State":"Committed",
    "History":"test1"
}

Please make sure that you have enabled Cors.

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
    public class TicketController : ApiController
    {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case decorating the parameter class with the `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]` attribute from Newtonsoft did the trick.

For example:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("MyRoute")]
public IHttpActionResult DoWork(MyClass args)
{
   ...
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]
public Class MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this character '\' in your json query in Postman, you should escape it if you need the character '\' in the json string value.

Example:

```
{
    "path": "C:\\Users\\Test\\Documents\\test.txt"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

Looking in different comments and other forums, I mix some snippets and For me, this code works...

... In the Controller

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] string jsonData)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, jsonData);            

        try 
        {
            string jsonString = jsonData.ToString();
            JArray jsonVal = JArray.Parse(jsonString) as JArray;
            dynamic mylist= jsonVal;
            foreach (dynamic myitem in mylist)
            {
                string strClave=string.Empty;
                string strNum=string.Empty;
                string strStatus=string.Empty;

                strClave = myitem.clave;
                strNum=myitem.num;
                strStatus = myitem.status; 
            }
```

... in the WebApiConfig.cs include this line for avoid the null value in the [FromBody] variable **var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType().First();**

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    { 
            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                            name: "DefaultApi",
                            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
                        );
            var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();  /*this line makes no more null when use [FromBody]*/
}
```

.... in the client side , the mos important is concatenate the equal sign before the serialized data (  **string json = "=" + SerialData;**  )

for seralize I'm using

```
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new 
System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

        List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> row;
        foreach (DataRow dr in DsCnx.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in DsCnx.Tables[0].Columns)
            {
                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            rows.Add(row);
        }
        SerialData= serializer.Serialize(rows);
       PostRequest("http://localhost:53922/api/Demo", SerialData);
```

this is my PostRequest function, here the Content Type thet I use is **httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";**:

```
private static string PostRequest(string url, string SerialData)
    {         
        string result = String.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "=" + SerialData;  
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        try
        {
            using (var response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (httpWebRequest.HaveResponse && response != null)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            if (e.Response != null)
            {
                using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response)
                {
                    using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                    {
                        string error = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        result = error;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return result.ToString();

    }
```

here is the links where i found one code example for reference :

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Aug/30/Using-JSONNET-for-dynamic-JSON-parsing#jobject-and-jarray-in-aspnet-web-api

https://blog.codenamed.nl/2015/05/12/why-your-frombody-parameter-is-always-null/

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP was originally sending a single string, but for future reference, it is also worth noting that malformed JSON will also arrive as `null` into the post method. In my case, a missing comma between two properties caused what was otherwise fine, to break.

Answer (score 0):

I have been stuck with this problems hours,I almost tried everything mentioned  or GPT indicated .At last ,I realize
there must be somethings  others cause this .Yes, some safeguard like software in the platform changed  it's strategy .When the  strategy removed ,all the things worked...,I changed zero code !

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

I tried many of the answers in this thread and none of them worked for me. Then I came across this answer to a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40853424/2120023 where he mentions `HttpContext.Request.Body` so another search and I found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1302851/2120023 which gave me `HttpContext.Current` so I finally got this to work using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Get("value");
```

My request from Postman:

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://example.com/token' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'value=test'
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, with or without [FromBody] tag when uploading image via AJAX call sending raw data. When **request is too big** controler dumps it (variable = null) so the solution was to increase maximal request size, resize image or similar approach.

Approach with increasing request size is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16403447

Answer (score -3):

This link helped me: http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/

Basically it says that you should use an empty name for the parameter:

```
public string Post([FromBody]string myParameter){ 
...
}  

$.post("/api/dosomething", { '' : "myvalue" });
```

Comment: fyi: chrome is throwing a red fire alarm alert on that url , saying it's malware .  not sure if it's a false positive ,but *be warned*