# jQuery posts null instead of JSON to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I can't seem to get this to work... I have some jQuery like this on the client:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/report/reportexists/",
    data: JSON.stringify({ "report":reportpath }),
    success: function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fileExists = true;
        } else {
            fileExists = false;
        }
    }
});
```

And in my Web.API controller I have a method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool ReportExists( [FromBody]string report )
{
    bool exists = File.Exists(report);
    return exists;
}
```

I'm just checking to see if a file lives on the server, and to return a bool as to whether it does or not.  The report string I am sending is a UNC path, so reportpath looks like '\\some\path\'.

I can fire the script okay, and hit a breakpoint in my ReportExists method, but the report variable is always null.

What am I doing wrong?

I also see a way to post with .post and postJSON.  Maybe I should be using one of those? If so, what would my format be?

**Update:**  An additional clue maybe- if I remove [FromBody] then my breakpoint doesnt get hit at all- 'No http resource was found that matches the request'.  Examples I am looking at show that [FromBody] isn't needed...?

Comment: `$.ajax` would be more appropriate for this situation since you may also need to include `contentType: "application/json"` as an option to `$.ajax`

Comment: Make sure to check your ModelState for errors in case something went wrong when binding parameters.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So I found the problem, and the solution.  So, first thing first.  The contentType cannot be 'application/json', it has to be blank (default to  application/x-www-form-urlencoded I believe).  Although it seems you have to SEND json, but without a name in the name value pair.  Using JSON.stringify also messes this up. So the full working jQuery code is like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/slideid/reportexists",
    data: { "": reportpath },
    success: function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fileExists = true;
        } else {
            fileExists = false;
        }
    }
});
```

On the Web.API side, you MUST have the [FromBody] attibute on the parameter, but other than this it's pretty standard.  The real problem (for me) was the post.

In Fiddler, the request body looked like this "=%5C%5Croot%5Cdata%5Creport.html"

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null) post really had the answer, and linked to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1#sending_simple_types) article which was also very helpful.

Comment: +1000 if i could. The only post that completely fixed my problem.

Comment: Yes, this works when you have a simple data type and not using a DTO or model. I finally gave up on everything that in theory should have worked and just did it exactly like this answer and it works.

Comment: what if you have 2 parameters?!

Comment: @K-Dawg, you'd pass a JSON object, such as `{ id: 12345, name: "Jane Smith" }`

Answer (score 13):

`jQuery.ajax()` by default sets the contentType to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.  You could send the request in `application/json` instead.  Also, you should send your data as a string and it will get model bind to the `report` parameter for your post method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/report/reportexists/",
    contentType:  "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(reportpath),
    success: function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            fileExists = true;
        } else {
            fileExists = false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes, content type is often the issue.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me, all other approaches didn't:

```
function addProduct() {
        var product = { 'Id': 12, 'Name': 'Maya', 'Category': 'newcat', 'Price': 1234 };             
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../api/products",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: product,
            dataType: "json",
             success: function (result) {

            },
            error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                alert(exception);
            }
        });
    }
```

Serverside:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public Product[] AddNewProduct([FromBody]Product prod)
    {
        new List<Product>(products).Add(prod);
        return products;
    }
```

Comment: I overhand the plain JSON object, no stringify needed !

Comment: Thanks,really thanks, after many searches finally this worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVC's `FromBody` attribute, the MVC binder treats this as an optional parameter. This means you need to be *explicit* about the Parameter names even if you've only got a single `FromBody` parameter.

You should be able to work with something as simple as this:

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public bool ReportExists( [FromBody]string report )
{
    bool exists = File.Exists(report);
    return exists;
}
```

**Javascript**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/report/reportexists/",
    data: { "report":reportpath },
    success: function(exists) {
    ...
```

**You must ensure that your data object in jQuery matches the parameter names of your Controllers *exactly*.**

Answer (score -1):

$.post served the purpose for me. Remove the [FromBody] from webapi and give the url in the url parameter of the $.post in jquery client. It worked!