# JQuery values passed to WebApi is always null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am having trouble with Web Api and was hoping someone here might be able to help me.

I have a jQuery method as follows ...

```
    function OnInsert(evt) {
        var truckId = $("#txtTruckId").val();
        var truckReg = $("#txtTruckReg").val();
        var description = $("#txtDescription").val();
        var condition = $("#txtCondition").val();
        var data = '{"obj":{"TruckId":"' + truckId + '","Reg":"' + truckReg +
                   '","Description":"' + description + '","Condition":"' + condition + '"}}';
        var json = JSON.stringify(data)

        $.ajax({
            url: '/api/Values',
            cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            data: json,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (results) {
                $("#txtTruckId").val('');
                $("#txtTruckReg").val('');
                $("#txtDescription").val('');
                $("#txtCondition").val('');
                $.getJSON("api/Values", LoadCustomers);
                alert('Truck Added !');
            }
        })
    }
```

When I debug that the 'data' variable successfully captures the data.

I then have a function in my WebApi controller ...

```
    // POST api/values
    public void Post(TruckInfo obj)
    {
        WebApiTestEntities db = new WebApiTestEntities();

        db.TruckInfoes.Add(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

However, when I debug thst all of the parameters are showing a null value.

I found this:

http://kennytordeur.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/web-api-passing-complex-type-in-json.html

Which states I need the following line of code in the Global.asax but that hasn't worked.

```
ValueProviderFactories.Factories.Add(new JsonValueProviderFactory());
```

I also found this which kind of comes up with an answer but after trying to alter my code so it looks like the code they have written it still doesn't work.

[jQuery posts null instead of JSON to ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779679/web-api-and-jquery-json-post-null-value)

Is any one able to help?

Thanks in advance

Lex

Comment: Could you post the `TruckInfo` definition?

Comment: Darin has answered my question below. Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start by fixing your JSON:

```
var data = {
    truckId: truckId, 
    reg: truckReg, 
    description: description, 
    condition: condition
};
var json = JSON.stringify(data);
```

and then make sure you specify the correct content type request header:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/Values',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: json,
    success: function (results) {
        $("#txtTruckId").val('');
        $("#txtTruckReg").val('');
        $("#txtDescription").val('');
        $("#txtCondition").val('');
        $.getJSON("api/Values", LoadCustomers);
        alert('Truck Added !');
    }
});
```

> I found this:
>
> http://kennytordeur.blogspot.co.uk/2012/12/web-api-passing-complex-type-in-json.html
>
> Which states I need the following line of code in the Global.asax but
>   that hasn't worked.

No, no, no. Not necessary as long as you format properly your JSON request, the Web API will bind it to your model.

Comment: should remove `obj` out of data?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. That has got it passing the values correctly now :) 

Can I ask another question? 

In my controller I am not sure on my code. When it gets to "SaveChanges" it throws the following error ...

Unable to update the EntitySet 'TruckInfo' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.

Comment: @LexEichner: please ask another question on SO instead via comments

Comment: I don't know. This has nothing to do with the Web API but is probably related to the underlying data access technology you are using. Probably EF or something. You should post another question outside of the context of Web API where you would show your entities, their values, and the query you are using.

Comment: +1 for No No No - the only thing I had wrong was the contentType

Comment: Thanks, this resolved my own issue with posting data to a Web Api REST controller.