# Parameters null in Web API ajax Call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

This is the first time i'm working with Web API. i'm trying to call a web api through a jquery ajax call. ajax call hits the web api action successfully but the string parameter "xx" is always null.

**Ajax call**

```
 var x = "chamara";
   $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: 'http://localhost:1557/api/values/mytest',
   data: '{"xx":"' + x + '"}',
   dataType: 'json',
   });
```

**Web Api action.**

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
 public void mytest([FromBody]string xx)
 { 
  string a = xx;

 }
```

**web api routes configuration.**

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var x = "chamara";
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost:1557/api/values/mytest',
    data: { '' : x },
    dataType: 'json',
});
```

I encountered the same thing this morning. I'm not sure why and I feel like there should be a better way, but it worked for me.

Alternatively, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779679/web-api-and-jquery-json-post-null-value) where the solutions suggest setting the `contentType` to `application/json`.

Comment: mmm interesting..i got it working too but looks like it's not working for multiple parameters. any way thanks for the answer

Comment: hello. check here http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/ [FromBody] accepts Only one parameter per method

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this simple code in JQuery to solve all my Microsoft .NET WebApi woes:

```
$.webApi = function (method, url, data) {
    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: method,
        data: typeof (data) === "object" ? JSON.stringify(data) : data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json"
    })
};
```

I call it like this:

```
$.webApi("POST", "http://url", {object:data});
```

Makes everything nice and simple.  And I don't have to remember all the settings every time.