# Body JSON data not received in MVC 5 wep api method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc

In my MVC 5 Web API application, i have a method with signature

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostDefects(int user, string order, string mode, [FromBody]List<Defect> defects)
```

This **API method** is called from **jQuery** as following

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/postdefects/123/456/myMode",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(priv.DefectList),
        success: function () {
            alert('REST call OK');
        },
        error: function() { 
            alert('REST call not OK') 
        },
        cache: false
    });
```

On **5 computers** this is working without any problem, except **2 computers**. For 1 of these computers, the issue got auto-solved without doing anything from my side... On the other one I still have the issue left, and I don't get it solved there.

When I am calling this API from my html page, I receive a 200 (OK) response, but my json body JSON.stringify(priv.DefectList) is not received in the API method. When checking in Fiddler afterwards, I can clearly see that the POST method is receiving the 200 (OK) response, and that the body was sent to the API method. Inside my API method however, I don't receive the object.

My web browser is Google Chrome 42.0.2311.135 m.

Any help would be great!

This is my Defect class

```
public partial class Defect
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string operation { get; set; }
    public string part_nbr { get; set; }
    public string tool { get; set; }
    public string imgName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> imgWidth { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> imgHeight { get; set; }
    public double xPos { get; set; }
    public double yPos { get; set; }
    public int reason { get; set; }
    public string reasonText { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> isRepaired { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> createdTS { get; set; }
    public string severity { get; set; }
    public string mode { get; set; }
    public string badge_nbr { get; set; }
}
```

And this is an example of the data that is passed

```
[  
    {  
        "order":"F00000021489",
        "operation":"0010",
        "part_nbr":"1741845",
        "reason":"6",
        "reasonText":"RWK06 Vosk - poškodenie",
        "xPos":417,
        "yPos":390,
        "imgWidth":880,
        "imgHeight":824,
        "imgName":"1741845_A.png",
        "createdTS":"2015-05-07T08:12:12.109Z",
        "tool":"1741845T05",
        "mode":"REWORK",
        "badge_nbr":"0180371"
    }
]
```

Comment: Could you please add the code for your `Defect` class? Also, an example of the json sent in the request would be useful, my best guess is that your problem is related to the deserialization of the model.

Comment: Hi Elolos, I updated my post and attached the defect class and an example.

Comment: Btw... imho, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the jQuery code. When i use the Fiddler composer, and attach the body to it, it's also not working. I'm entering the API than, but no JSON body is attached.

Comment: The following answer seems like a possible solution to your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27508791/1598534

Comment: Thanks elolos, this solved it!!!