# Post from JQuery Json to ASP.Net MVC: the 2 parameters are null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc

I came through old Q&A like [jQuery posts null instead of JSON to ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779679/jquery-posts-null-instead-of-json-to-asp-net-web-api) (on this site),
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-post-frombody-parameters-to-web-api/ or
 https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods...
I tried all the hints and solutions, but I still have no values in my controller.
Here is my code:

Client HTML file :

```
var coup = { Token: token, MotPropose: RecupMot() };
var coupJSON = JSON.stringify(coup);

$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: urlJeu,
            dataType: 'json', 
            data: coupJSON,
            success: function (reponseJSON) {
                 /* CODE HERE */
            },
        });
```

Which sends correctly the following JSON (says Fiddle):

```
{"Token":103,"MotPropose":"ravoi"}
```

(BTW, I'm concerned about the missing " around the int 103, no?)

Server C# controller and object:

```
public object Post([FromBody]CoupMeliMelo coup)
{
    return Ok(jeu.JouerLeCoup(coup));
}

public class CoupMeliMelo : ICoup
{
    public string MotPropose { get; set; }
    public int Token { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when the JSON comes to the controller, the object *coup* is created, but MotPropose is null and Token is 0.

I'm stuck! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you ensure RecupMot() function return string value?

Comment: Yes, actually it returns "ravoi".

Comment: Try adding `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to your ajax call.

Comment: Is this a Web API controller or a MVC Controller?

Comment: It is a Web API controller.

Comment: I tried `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` unsuccessfully. I undersrtood it was implicit.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there's no reason to call stringify.  Just post the object.  Second, send the content as application/json.

```
var coup = { Token: token, MotPropose: RecupMot() };

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: urlJeu,
        dataType: 'json', 
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: coup,
        success: function (reponseJSON) {
             /* CODE HERE */
        },
    });
```

Finally, the `[FromBody]` attribute is not applicable to ASP.NET MVC, only WebApi.  You don't need it.

```
public object Post(CoupMeliMelo coup)
{
    return Ok(jeu.JouerLeCoup(coup));
}
```

Comment: Actually, it is WebApi, hence I kept `[FromBody]`
Then I removed `stringify`, then added the ContentType, but no success...

(Sorry for the delay: I jumped to VS 2015, with some trouble...)