# jquery post single integer value to asp.net webapi the parameter dictionary error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to send a post call from jquery to asp.net webapi with [FromBody] for single integer value.

getting error saying the parameters dictionary contains a null entry.

here is my code:

```
[HttpPost()]
public IHttpActionResult ChartData([FromUri] int appID,[FromBody] int aID)
{
    return Ok(jsonData);
}
```

```
function GetCallMethod(url, successCallback) {
    var id = 1234;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType:  "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({'aID':id}),
        success: successCallback,
        error: function (err) {
            console.log('Error getting data');
        }
    });
}
```

The `aID` in the controller is getting `0`

Comment: The [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779679/jquery-posts-null-instead-of-json-to-asp-net-web-api) seems to suggest removing the `contentType` definition and submitting an empty `key`, like `data: { "": id}`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the url.

If you look closely at the API you will see that it takes two parameters. The first one, the `appID` comes from the url (it would be in the form of baseurl/XXXX where XXXX is the application id in numeric format - similar to www.host.com/application/1234 or a variation thereof) and the second is the `aID` which comes from the request body.

What is happening is that the web api is trying to figure out the parameters you are passing to the end point by constructing a dictionary out of combination of body and url parameters. Since your url parameter is most likely non existent - it is throwing an exception when it constructs that dictionary.

Look at the route registration for the particular endpoint and check-out where the `appID` has to exist within the url.