# json string on POST to MVC action method using AJAX is null

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am getting a hard time to find out why the string sent via AJAX request is null. Console.WriteLine(data) shows empty. Status is 200 OK. If I add some code to parse the string received, I get an error stating that JObject.Parse cannot be null. I don't know what am I missing. The javascript code is ok. The action method also seems ok, but my knowledge on Asp.Net Core and MVC is very scarce, so I am not sure. Can someone please point out what am I missing?

The javascript code:

```
    let obj = {email: email_address.value};
    let objStringified = JSON.stringify(obj);
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
       data: objStringified,
       url: '@Url.Action("ReturnCheckAccountDuplication")',
       dataType: 'text',
       success: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
       },
       error: function(error) {
          console.log("Keep trying", error);
       }
    });
```

C# code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReturnCheckAccountDuplication([FromBody] string data)
{
   Console.WriteLine(data);
   JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(data);
   string email = (string)jObject["email"];
   bool emailExists = CheckAccountDuplication.Get(email);
   string returnResult = emailExists.ToString();
   return Content(returnResult);
}
```

The solution on the controller side is

```
public class AccountCheckModel
{
   public string Email { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReturnCheckAccountDuplication([FromBody] AccountCheckModel data)
{
   string result = CheckAccountDuplication.Get(data.Email).ToString();
   return Content(result);
}
```

Thanks to all the members who commented on my problem, especially John Glenn who provided a solution. I had been trying for several days but without success. My knowledge of Asp.Net Core is very poor indeed. Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery posts null instead of JSON to ASP.NET Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779679/jquery-posts-null-instead-of-json-to-asp-net-web-api)

Comment: Hello. It didn't worked for me. I tested the solution described and still got an error. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 's') at Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(String json, JsonLoadSettings settings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to create a model representing the JSON data that your controller will receive. For example, create a class like so:

```
public class AccountCheckModel
{
    public string email { get; set }
}
```

Then, use it as the parameter for your controller method:

```
public ActionResult ReturnCheckAccountDuplication([FromBody] AccountCheckModel data)
```

This is the preferred way to access the request body. To get the request body as a string, you have to jump through some [serious hoops](https://markb.uk/asp-net-core-read-raw-request-body-as-string.html).

Comment: Great! It works. I changed the controller code and is now as below:
public class AccountCheckModel
{
   public string email { get; set; }
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReturnCheckAccountDuplication([FromBody] AccountCheckModel data){
   string email = data.email;
   bool emailExists = CheckAccountDuplication.Get(email);
   string result = emailExists.ToString();
   return Content(result);
}

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to send your data via `AJAX` to your `Controller`:

```
var json = {
       email: email_address.value
};

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   data: {'json': JSON.stringify(json)},
   url: '@Url.Action("ReturnCheckAccountDuplication")',
   dataType: 'json',
   success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
   },
   error: function(error) {
      console.log("Keep trying", error);
   }
});
```

And your `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ReturnCheckAccountDuplication(string json)
{
   Console.WriteLine(json);
   JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
   string email = (string)jObject["email"];
   bool emailExists = CheckAccountDuplication.Get(email);
   string returnResult = emailExists.ToString();
   return Content(returnResult);
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with just a small change (in dataType, I declared text instead of json). But is not working. The string json is still null in the controller.

Comment: @LuisRitoFilipe Well isn't it obvious from the line `data: {'json': JSON.stringify(json)},`, that you are sending the data as `JSON` so why would you even change the dataType to `text`?

Comment: @LuisRitoFilipe If you did not change the `dataType` to `text`, this would have worked as expected and you would not have to go through the pain of creating models for one field.

Comment: Rahul Sharma, I tried dataType : json but it didn't work, then I tried dataType : text and it didn't work either. But I changed dataType to text because I expect from server a simple string and not a string in JSON format. But even so, this is not a reason for the controller to recognise the data sent as null. Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: @LuisRitoFilipe Then it might the problem in your `@Url.Action`, since you did not mention the `Controller`, your URL would be: `url: '@Url.Action("ReturnCheckAccountDuplication", "{Your Controller Name")'` .Right now you are just sending one string so it is simple but as soon as you have more complexity with more data then eventually you would consider sending it as `JSON`

Comment: Rahul Sharma, sure, if I want to return json from server (in case of more complex data), the dataType must be json. But in my specific case I just need a simple string (True/False). Kind regards.