# SOAP UI Post using json

Tags: c#, rest, soapui

I have a api method with the signature as follows:

```
public HttpResponseMessage TestMethod(string id, [FromBody] MyObject object)
```

I use soap UI and add the following json:

```
{"Name":"test"}
```

where Name is the only property I have in MyObject.

This works fine but when I add the [Serializable] attribute at the top of MyObject and run my SOAPUI request again the Name attribute doesn't get bound anymore.  Any ideas why this would be?

Comment: I think you need to add KnownTypeAttribute as well along with serializable attribute

Comment: A bit old, this was already solved here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null