# Web api get call but in reponse it says undefined

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to call a web api POST method using angular js it get call.
I try from postman utility it also get call and in respose give a json data.But in angular side i am not getting data in response.

my services in angular js

```
 var _getProjects = function (searchText) {
    debugger;
    return $http.post(URL + 'api/project/GetProjectDetails?searchText='+ searchText).then(function (response) {
        return response;
    });
};
```

and below is my web api

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/project/GetProjectDetails")]
    public List<GetKeywordsBasisData_Result> GetProjectDetails(string searchText)
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
        {
            return projectProvider.GetProjectDetails(searchText).ToList();
        }
        return new List<GetKeywordsBasisData_Result>();
    }
```

Comment: Open inspect element and click on network tab. Now click on the button. That will tell you which url are you calling. Copy that url and compare with your postman url.

Comment: To open inspect element right click on the browser

Comment: Why do you call return twice in your _getProjects $http.post?

Comment: Multiple comments here: 1) the post data structure, all I see is a string. Can we also see the signature of the WebApi? 2) routing might not be correct, can you include routing info for your web api call in your .net code? 3) You never actually do anything with the response, you just return it but that does not do anything. You need a callback method that you can pass the results to. Finally, for your question the only real code of interest is the WebApi controller structure and the angular factory code.

Comment: See previous so answer: [Post parameter is always null](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13030451/1260204). This does not address the other possible problems I mentioned.

Comment: ya but now the web api get call but in postman it give a response .but in angular js respose it says undefined

Comment: You need a callback. The response from your post happens async at a later point in time. You want to pass your function a function to call after you get a response. That function should accept whatever it is you are giving back so you can do something with it.

Comment: basically my web request not get access the web api because of CORS files are missing but after adding in web api issue get resolved, Thanks to all for helping to resolve the issues

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a callback. Http Calls on `$http` happen asynchronously, you need to pass in a method to call once the call completes. Something like this. The parameter myCallback is a function that takes in the expected response, you can then process it (or whatever) inside that function.

```
 function (searchText, myCallback) {
    $http.post(URL + 'api/project/GetProjectDetails?searchText='+ searchText).then(function (response) {
        myCallback(response);
    });
};
```

You can then call it from your controller like this assuming getProjects is your factory method. Also assuming that $scope is a field on your controller.

```
var me = this;
getProjects('somethingToSearchFor', function(results){
    me.$scope.results = results;
});
```

Comment: `.success` is depricated. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice. I'd argue that with this code that you'd much rather just want to return the promise. `return $http.post(URL);` but it does render the entire function pretty useless.

Comment: in console it show like this         project:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:53018/api/project/GetProjectDetails?searchText=ios. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:49938' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: @MayurSingh are you using chrome ? see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28547288/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-err)

Comment: Sir the api is not call because of CORS plugin are missing . because my request get block when i call the api.After adding plugin files its work and results is shown

Comment: @MayurSingh - glad to hear it!

Comment: @Igor please vote my question so that i can get some reputation points

Comment: @ippi please vote my question so that i can get some reputation points