# asp.net webapi 2 post parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have been trying to figure this our for the last hour, but I can't see what's wrong with it

the post is from a xamarin app that I'm writing, using restsharp portable client

```
POST http://192.168.30.103:8080/api/Order HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic xxxx
Content-Length: 51
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: 192.168.30.103:8080
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

{"CheckinCount":1,"EventId":16630,"OrderNo":470292}
```

It hits the server Post API correctly, but the parameter is always null

```
 public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string source) {
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(source);
        int checkInCount = data.CheckinCount;
        int eventId = data.EventId;
        int orderNo = data.OrderNo;
        return Ok();
    }
```

I can't figure out why...

Comment: Why do you do the deserialization manually and not leave it to web api?

Comment: `{"CheckinCount":1,"EventId":16630,"OrderNo":470292}` isn't a string. It's an object instead.

Comment: I didn't want to add another DTO for a last minute API addon, but I'll give it a whirl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you always send the same parameters? If so, could you create a static object instead of using a dynamic one? Something like an `EventRequest` that you pass in instead?

```
public class EventRequest
{
    public int CheckinCount { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
}
```

Your `Post` action then becomes:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(EventRequest request) {
    // do something with request
    return Ok();
}
```

Comment: thanks that worked, however i'd still be interested if I wanted to read raw json from body, how would I do it ?

Comment: Just for my own note, if you forget public on the properties, it won't give you an error, just an empty object with null values for properties.  I promise to never ever copy and paste code again!

Answer (score 1):

For me, it was the value of that is being sent by checkbox. Checkbox was sending **true** but for JSON, value must be between quotations i.e. **"true"**.

Answer (score 0):

related entry from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null?rq=1)

in short, when sending simple values which are to be picked up using [frombody] attribute on the server side, you have to prefix the value with =
e.g. =testValue

but its probably better just to use JSON Objects and object bindings on the API, even for simple values