# ajax post .net web api parameter is null

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

Please be gentle with me. Im not an expert.

Im posting a valid json (validated)

```
{
"Stats": [{
    "userName": "sadf",
    "id": "128",
    "score": "7"
}, {
    "userName": "fa",
    "id": "417",
    "score": "3"
}]
}



// POST api/comment
public void Post(List<Stat> Stats)
{
  string break= "Breakpoint here";
}


public class Stat
{
public string userName { get; set; }
public string id { get; set; }
public string score { get; set; }
}
```

No matter what, then I only get Stats == null in Post(List Stats)

This is the javascript code:

```
var stats = [{ "userName": "sadf" },
                { "userName": "fa" }];

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:56887/api/comment",
            data: JSON.stringify({ Stats: stats }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(stats, function (k, v) {
                    alert(v.position);
                });
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);

            }
        });
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You need to add the [FromBody] attribute to the method. See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10986030/3279876

Comment: I have already tried that without result.

Comment: In that case show your entire ajax post code.

Comment: @sami Just updated with javascript

Comment: Try changing data: JSON.stringify({ Stats: stats }) to data: JSON.stringify(stats)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a view model that will match this JSON structure:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public IList<Stat> Stats { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take as parameter:

```
public void Post(MyViewModel model)
{
    // model.Stats will contain the desired collection here
}
```

If you want to bind directly to a `List<Stat>` then all you need to do is get rid of the `Stats` property that you artificially introduce when stringifying:

```
data: JSON.stringify(stats),
```

Also you might want to reconsider this parameter `dataType: "json",` especially if your controller action is `void` and doesn't return anything at the moment which obviously is wrong and it is not how controller action signatures are supposed to look like in ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: data: JSON.stringify(stats),  That did the trick. Thanks very much.