# C# Web API Always getting a null value on a POST

Tags: c#, api, post

[Screenshot of Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsZTL.png)

I've seen this question asked a few times but with no answer which seems to help or really fit my case.  Here's my code first:

So here's my code; the value is always null no matter what I do, and by adding the [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost] decoration I now get an error stating that the route doesn't support posts.  I need some help.

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public string Post(string value)
{
    return value;
}
```

Here is what I'm posting via Postman; I'm putting this in the body:

"test"

No matter what I put in the body, the value of "value" is always null.  I'm not sure what to do here, nothing seems to work.  I even changed the decoration to just [HttpPost].  Gets work just fine for this controller, it's just the post which is failing miserably.

Comment: But a post doesn't use body without [FromBody] attribute, I think - maybe this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null

Comment: I've updated the signature to

`public string Post([FromBody]string value)`

Still the same result.

Comment: I updated my original post with a screenshot of Postman.  I'm in agreement that I'm probably not passing the value correctly or something similar, but I'm at a loss as to where I'm going wrong.

Comment: That's an array of objects, with a property of "value" with a value of "test".  It needs to be *just* a string.  Try just sending *test* with nothing around it, not even quotes.

Comment: Unfortunately the same thing, I get a return of null.  I did set a breakpoint so the correct method is being called, but the value of "value" is still null.  Talk about frustrating :(

Comment: [Postman](http://i67.tinypic.com/29p5575.png)  <-- Should be a link to my Postman call

Comment: Wow, that IS frustrating. When you created the web api project, what did you select, version-wise (this isn't core, is it?)? I'm going to throw together a little test and see if it works for me.

Comment: Definitely not core, and thanks for your help.

Comment: ok, mine works but was a pain  =) Will write up something in a few here.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public ActionResult PostName([FromBody] string value)
 {
  ...
 }
```

And put "value" in Body type raw in PostMan.

```
{
    "value" : "hi"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately still null.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I created a simple Web API project using Visual Studio, so it has all the default routes and whatnot.

[image]

Then I grabbed postman and fiddled with it, until I got it to post properly to the endpoint. Note the format header of application/json, but since we're only sending a string, it's JUST a string.

[image]

Now the value is here in the breakpoint

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I did and it epically failed for me :(   I even tried a curl passing in a string and it failed.   I've no idea why, I've not had this type of trouble before.  However, I did get a solution in that by using data models within the code and then passing in json which corresponds to the model, I'm able to get the posts to work.  So I guess this can be marked solved?