# AngularJS passes null parameter with bool value to asp.net controller

Tags: json, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using asp.net core MVC 3.1.0. I make a call from AngularJS to MVC controller to submit form. But the parameter object is passing null to controller:

AngularJS:

```
$scope.minfo = 0;
$scope.submit = function () {   
    var model = {"obj": {"Email": $scope.email,"Password": $scope.pw,"memberInformed":$scope.minfo};       
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Register',
        data: model
    });
};
```

Controller c#:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Register(Register obj)
{       
    //...
    return View();
}
```

Update: 
boolean input field:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="minfo" ng-model="minfo" ng-true-value="1" ng-false-value="0" required />
```

I can send parameters without `memberInformed` boolean parameter. Otherwise the object is null. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Which version of MVC are you using? Please try modifying controller action signature to use [FromBody] . => `public IActionResult Register([FromBody]Register obj)`.

Comment: There is no need to stringify the data. The AngularJS frame work does that automatically.

Comment: Without stringfy it shows 'Object object', but I can see parameters with stringfy. The problem is they are null in the controller side. @georgeawg

Comment: Check the network tab of the Developer Console to see the request and debug it.

Comment: I updated my question @sam [FromBody] is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Post parameter is always null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984040/post-parameter-is-always-null)

Comment: @Zeynep, Thank you for updating the answer. I see obj is wrapped inside object (`{}`) again. could you just try sending {"Email": $scope.email,"Password": $scope.pw } to controller

Comment: using `ng-true-value` , minfo value won't be a boolean

Comment: When I remove them, if the field is unchecked, cannot get the value from checkbox @BillP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your controller action `public IActionResult Register(Register obj)` is taking Register viewmodel, please modify your angular code to send the obj without wrapping it inside `{}` as below:

```
$scope.submit = function () {   
    var model = {"Email": $scope.email,"Password": $scope.pw };       
    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/Register',
        data: model
    });
};
```

**UPDATE**: 
based on your update, you are trying to send int ($scope.minfo) to boolean data type memberInformed and hence the issue.

So, **either** change C# Register object's memberInformed property type from bool to int as shown below;

```
public class Register
{
    // Since you are sending integer value from angular, modify the data type to int from bool
    // public bool memberInformed { get; set; } 
    public int memberInformed { get; set; } 


    public string Email { get; set; } 

    public string Password { get; set; } 
}
```

**or** modify your angular and view code as below:

```
$scope.minfo = false;

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2"  ng-true-value="true" ng-false-value="false">
```

or you can skip ng-true-value and ng-false-value as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxModel.value2">
```

Comment: Sorry. As I was trying to shorten my question I've removed some parameters. I see that a bool parameter is the problem. I updated my question again. Your answer works without json.stringify by the way.

Comment: @Zeynep: I updated my answer to remove Json.stringify . Also, explained the issue with memberInformed. Please verify the Update section in my answer